# Matching all occurrences of a year

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match all the dates that are found in a string, here is the function

```
$description = "1999 2008 1998";

if(preg_match("/[12][0-9]{3}/", $description, $matches)){
   print_r($matches);
}
```

The problem is that only the first date is returned which is `1999`, I actually want to match all dates.

What should I change in the regex?

Comment: What if the year is not valid like 7777

Comment: @Baba 7777 would not be matched...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php
$description = "1999 2008 1998";

if(preg_match_all("/[12][0-9]{3}/", $description, $matches)){
   print_r($matches);
}
```

only difference is `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.

Comment: All this time an I didn't know that there was a preg_match_all, how embarrassing. thanks anyway

Comment: So this is all that you wanted?

Comment: Better that you ask the questions and learn than remain in the dark!

Comment: @mk_89 Well, don't be disappointed, but I didn't know about `preg_match_all` either, just started typing `preg_m` in google and the autosuggest spit it out, so I figured that's probably what you wanted and wrote the answer, anyway, if you could please check it so that others don't try to figure out an answer you already got.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$description = "1999 2008 1998";

$a = Array(preg_match_all('/(\d{4})*/', $description, $matches));

$count = count($matches);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $count + 2; $i++) {
    echo $matches[0][$i] . "\n";
}
?>
```

**output**

```
1999
2008
1998
```